# Attachments.Add when file is open, with Office365, using Outlook VBA that worked in older version of Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, email-attachments

I migrated from Office 2016 to Office 365. I have code that has worked for years.

The code has an option to attach a file. If the file that is being attached is not open, it works. If the file is open, then I receive the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147024864 (80070020)

[image]

```vb
Sub Email(Optional vToAddress As String, Optional vSubject As String, Optional vEmailRange As String = "", Optional vCCAddress As String, Optional vBCCAddress As String = "", Optional vAttachmentFullPath As String)

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object
        
    If vEmailRange <> "" Then
        Application.GoTo Range(vEmailRange)
        Selection.Copy
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = vToAddress
        If vCCAddress <> "" Then .CC = vCCAddress
        If vBCCAddress <> "" Then .BCC = vBCCAddress
        .Subject = vSubject
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        '.HTMLBody = ""
        If vAttachmentFullPath <> "" And Dir(vAttachmentFullPath) <> "" Then
            .Attachments.Add vAttachmentFullPath
        End If
            
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
            
        If vEmailRange <> "" Then
            oRng.Collapse 1
            oRng.Paste
        End If
           
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
       
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot test it, not having that Excel version available, but I cannot deny its behavior, neither. Maybe Microsoft representative thought that you can modify the respective file and risk to npt send final version... Or not. So, you should live with that, I think. I would suggest you to use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs` method using the same path, but placing "Copy_" as prefix of the existing file. Using this method, **the saved file is not open**, so you can attach it, then delete (`kill`) it...

Comment: If the issue is an open file, two solutions occur to me: either close the file (may not be wanted) or create a temporary copy you can attach to the e-mail.

Comment: Maybe the right question is why the file is open? Where does it come from?